# Ionic 2 / Cordova: Plugins Not Found

Tags: javascript, xcode, cordova, plugins, ionic2

I seem to be having an issue with all Cordova plugins that I am adding to my project. For this question, I will reference specifically the SplashScreen plugin.

The process that I take when building my project for IOS is as follows:

- ionic cordova platform add ios
- ionoc cordova prepare ios
- ionic cordova build ios

At this point, the build will fail with an error 65 on xcode args. After some googling, I found that a solution to this is to perform ionic cordova platform update ios, this fixes the problem and allows me to compile and run my application, yay!

The reason that I have included the above details is, I am worried that perhaps updating the platform is for some reason causing the plugins not to load / be included. Just a thought but thought I would include that process for reference.

When running my project in the IOS emulator on mac, I get the following plugin errors in the console for xCode, this error message is specifically for the StatusBar but is the same for all other plugins I have added:

`2017-08-13 20:41:36.391 Shokuni[20906:1123728] CDVPlugin class CDVStatusBar (pluginName: statusbar) does not exist.`

The plugins then reset due to page load…
`2017-08-13 20:41:37.724 Shokuni[20906:1123728] Resetting plugins due to page load.`

Then i get the following error about the status bar, which I assume is because it is being attempted to be used on the first page loaded in the project
`2017-08-13 20:41:38.883 Shokuni[20906:1123728] CDVPlugin class CDVStatusBar (pluginName: StatusBar) does not exist.`

`2017-08-13 20:41:38.883 Shokuni[20906:1123728] ERROR: Plugin 'StatusBar' not found, or is not a CDVPlugin. Check your plugin mapping in config.xml.`

Inside xCode, in the File Explorer panel on the left, there are no plugins inside the plugin folder, I am wondering whether this could potentially be an issue? I can however see that the plugins that I have installed are available at `staging/www/plugins`

Anybody had this problem before or knows about what may be going on? If so I would be very grateful.

Comment: I generally don't trust the update command. As long as you haven't written custom code in the platforms folder, try deleting platforms/ and plugins/ then run prepare again.

Comment: @connor neither do i, however I have found that when I do this, I cannot successfully archive and compile the project until it has been updated

Comment: Huh. Do you have more details on the error 65 and ionic thread?